# Making an efficient Java 8 sorted Spliterator from an array

Tags: java, java-8, spliterator

In Java 8, a variety of [convenient utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.html) are provided to build efficient Spliterators from arrays.  However, no factory methods are provided there to build a Spliterator with a comparator.  Clearly Spliterators are allowed to have attached comparators; they have a [`getComparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#getComparator--) method and a [`SORTED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#SORTED) property.

How are library authors supposed to build `SORTED` Spliterators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that it is not foreseen to have such a `Spliterator` with an order other than natural. But implementing it is not that hard. It could look like this:

```
class MyArraySpliterator implements Spliterator.OfInt {
    final int[] intArray;
    int pos;
    final int end;
    final Comparator<? super Integer> comp;

    MyArraySpliterator(int[] array, Comparator<? super Integer> c) {
        this(array, 0, array.length, c);
    }
    MyArraySpliterator(int[] array, int s, int e, Comparator<? super Integer> c) {
        intArray=array;
        pos=s;
        end=e;
        comp=c;
    }
    @Override
    public OfInt trySplit() {
        if(end-pos<64) return null;
        int mid=(pos+end)>>>1;
        return new MyArraySpliterator(intArray, pos, pos=mid, comp);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        if(pos<end) {
            action.accept(intArray[pos++]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        if(pos<end) {
            action.accept(intArray[pos++]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return end-pos;
    }
    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return SIZED|SUBSIZED|SORTED|ORDERED|NONNULL;
    }
    @Override
    public Comparator<? super Integer> getComparator() {
        return comp;
    }
}
```

But Java 8 is not entirely fixed yet. Maybe there will be a JRE-provided solution in the final.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an ORDERED Spliterator:

- by [starting from a Collection](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#ORDERED) with an appropriate `iterator()`:

  > A Collection has an encounter order if the corresponding Collection.iterator() documents an order. If so, the encounter order is the same as the documented order. Otherwise, a collection does not have an encounter order.

  Typically, `TreeSet.spliterator#getComparator` returns the TreeSet's Comparator, but `ArrayList.spliterator#getComparator` returns null: the order is by incrementing index.
- or, if you have an array, by using the new convenience methods provided in the `Arrays` helper class, such as [`Arrays.spliterator(double[])`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#spliterator-double%3aA-):

  > The spliterator reports Spliterator.SIZED, Spliterator.SUBSIZED, Spliterator.ORDERED, and Spliterator.IMMUTABLE.
- or (which is what `Arrays.spliterator` does) by explicitly providing characteristics, such as: `Spliterators.spliterator(array, Spliterator.ORDERED);`

When the collection is not associated with a particular comparator (or with arrays), it would make sense to sort before "spliterating".