# What would be a good use-case scenario for the Spliterator in Java 8?

Tags: java, data-structures, iterator, java-8, spliterator

What would be a good use-case scenario for the [`Spliterator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235606/understanding-spliterator-collector-and-stream-in-java-8) class in Java 8?

Comment: Spliterator, not SplitIterator. :-)

Comment: I found these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114015/why-does-iterablet-not-provide-stream-and-parallelstream-methods?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075860/making-an-efficient-java-8-sorted-spliterator-from-an-array which seem relevant for a Spliterator.

Comment: Streams are built from Spliterators. So, every time you would like to create a Stream from a collection, you would need to provide a Spliterator. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, an application developer would not consume the `Spliterator` API directly. But if you are providing an API, and implement your own collection-like class, you can implement `Spliterator` to adapt your collection to the `Stream` API. This supports a functional approach, parallel processing, and other features.

For example, I wrote a utility to enumerate IP addresses in a network, specified by CIDR notation. It's not really a collection; that is, it doesn't carry list of all of the addresses in memory at once, only the network number and netmask. But by exposing a `Spliterator`, it can be easily adapted to a `Stream`. (Each `Spliterator` just tracks the current IP address and maximum address in its share of the network.)

Another example from the core Java runtime is [`DirectoryStream` for traversing the file system.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-)

Answer (score 6):

Use case example: "Converts iterator to stream"

```
public static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToFiniteStream(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
   final Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator;
  return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Spliterator` is an extension of the timeless `Iterator` class that allows for splitting of a stream of objects to iterate over (`Stream` works by collecting the operations before iterating).

I cannot think of any times when the average developer would have to work with `Spliterator`. The [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) APIs are incredibly rich in Java 8, and in most cases you'd be better off using a vanilla `Collection` subclass instead of building your own `Stream` interface.

An example of when you might want to use `Spliterator` might be a library for [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) using a linked data structure over which the standard `Spliterator`/`stream()` is undefined.

Comment: `Spliterator` doesn't extend `Iterator`.

Comment: @erickson I did not mean inheritance. It continues the _concept_ of `Iterator`.